# Airplay options are hidden after initialise AudioUnit on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, audiounit, audiotoolbox, mpvolumeview

I'm using code from [here](http://www.stefanpopp.de/2011/capture-iphone-microphone/) to init Audio Unit. Problem is that I'm using Airplay (through MPVolumeView) inside my app and notice that just after initialise AudioProcessor (calling: [AudioProcessor alloc] init) all Airplay options are being hidden and I can select only between iPhone& IPhone Speaker (before the init I can see all my Airplay devices).

What on the init process cause that? Is there a way to use AudioUnit without causing this issue?

Thanks!